# RMySQL: Transforming extracted data

Tags: r, rmysql

I am trying to extract numeric data from a database where the columns have been set as `VARCHAR(100)`. All data in the relevant columns are numeric so there shouldn't be any problem extracting the data formatted as integer. Is there a nice way to do this in R?

Here is what I got:

```
m_df <- dbGetQuery(conn, paste("SELECT ", direc, " as Position, ", power, " as Power FROM ", table, 
                     " d LEFT JOIN files f on f.id=d.fileid WHERE parc='", parc, 
                     "' AND timestamp >= '", w_date[1], "' and timestamp <= '", w_date[2], 
                     "' AND plantnumber = ", w_mach, sep=""))
```

Executing the following:

```
sum(m_df$Power)
```

Produces this error:

```
Error in sum(m_df$Power) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Performing:

```
str(m_df)
```

Generates:

```
 'data.frame':   4317 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Position: chr  "280" "281" "288" "294" ...
 $ Power   : chr  "294" "342" "324" "284" ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to sum some characters and R is saying "WHAAAA?". The little snippet that follows reproduces your error.

```
(x.char <- sum(c("1", "2", "3")))
 Error in sum(c("1", "2", "3")) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
(sum(as.numeric(x.char)))
 [1] 6
```

Run `as.numeric` function on your data.frame and you're good to go.